# can users come to my site and spam Socket.emit(something);? or is there protection on this kind of security issue?

Tags: node.js, security, socket.io, server, client

i'm using socket.io and the client side looks like this.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.emit("sendData", "hello!");
</script>
```

im wondering whats stopping a random user, to join my site, look at the code, and add the following lines to it, using chromes code view app or something of the sorts:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        socket.emit("sendData", "hello!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I posted this on the security stackexchange. So I will post it here also for the google users:  
     
A year ago I had the same problem, so I created this module: http://npmjs.com/package/socket-anti-spam it basically keeps track of socket.id's spamming your socket.emit's and kicks them if they keep spamming. If they still persist then they get a temp ban. It's not a cover all because the bans are ip based though

Answer (score 6):

Yes, users can come to your site and do that.

There is nothing built into the browser or socket.io to stop a user from doing what you suggest.  If you want to protect against that, then you will have to implement your own protections.  I don't know what you're really trying to do so I can only make broad suggestions, but these are the kinds of things that can be done:

1. Implement user authentication so only confirmed, authenticated users can use your site.
2. Implement rate limiting on your server so that any users who are exceeding a normal expected real user rate of activity are disconnected and perhaps even eventually banned if abuse continues.
3. Use "real person detection" like captchas if you want to prevent bots from doing things on your site.  Or perhaps force use of a captcha only if the user appears to be doing more than is expected (e.g. a potential bot).
4. Detect non-original, repeated communication and disallow or block that (like what the loop you show would do).

Comment: @FelipeGarcia-Diaz - did this address your question?